# .htaccess redirect - how to and which directory?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory structure "like" this

- Root

- Sub Dir A

  Content

  Admin

And I have some files in Admin that I need to .htaccess forbid.  I know they should be outside the root but in this situation I cannot. What is the correct syntax for htaccess to redirect a direct request for say 'Sub Dir A/Admin/abc.php' (say a forbidden file) back to say Sub Dir A/Admin/index.php  - just an example. To note "abc.php" may be an include so it should only be a direct request.   Oh forgot to ask, which directory to put the .htaccess file in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** want to do this with mod_rewrite, then the rule can be:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^abc\.php$ http://www.example.com/subdir_a/admin/index.php [R=301,L]
```

This will issue 301 Permanent Redirect if you attempt to access `abc.php` directly.

This is to be place in .htaccess in `/subdir_a/admin/` folder.

If you wish -- you can place it in .htaccess file in website root folder -- then alter rewrite rule a bit to include the path to `abc.php`:

```
RewriteRule ^subdir_a/admin/abc\.php$ http://www.example.com/subdir_a/admin/index.php [R=301,L]
```

---

Alternatively you can issue 403 Access Denied response:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^abc\.php$ - [F,L]
```

---

The common practice is not to relay on .htaccess and mod_rewrite (that can be unavailable on some shared hosting plans or disabled for performance reasons) and use PHP-Script side checks:

1. To be placed in included/protected file (e.g. abc.php):

```
if (!defined('ENTRY_POINT_MARK')) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Access Denied', true, 403);
    exit();
}
```

2. To be placed in calling/master script (that you can access directly):

```
define('ENTRY_POINT_MARK', 'EntryPointMark');
```

Comment: LazyOne - Brill excellent explanation thanks a lot but --- always abut the file is .sqlite not php and I can still download by direct access OK not much in it (the sqlite) and is only for testing but I do need to prevent access.  May be best way to passwrd the admin dir?

Comment: It is up to you -- but I would block all requests to *.sqlite permanently (regardless of password protection) -- and only allow access to it via FTP. To block it globally (for the whole site), you can try this rule: `RewriteRule \.sqlite - [R=404,L]` (can be placed in website root .htaccess) -- it will issue 404 Not Found response, which you may consider a bit safer/friendlier than 403 (403 kind of tells: "file is may be here, but you cannot access it", while 404 tells: "dunno what are you talking about, not such file here -- thanks for visiting").

Comment: Again many many thanks some exceedingly good code here I have always used a slightly different version on defined('ENTRY_POINT_MARK') but yours is much nicer, the rewrite works a "treat" have also given db a "strange" extension and blocked that personally prefer 301 or 404's - again BRILL! :)

Comment: Sorry I know you have properly answered the question but you seem to know alot about htaccess - what is the rewrite rule to show subdrir/content/index.php as subdir/index.php in the browser?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^subdir/index\.php$ /subdrir/content/index.php [L]` -- that's if placed in htaccess in a folder above `/subdir/` (e.g. website root). Or `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ content/index.php [L]` if placed in `/subdir/.htaccess` (may need to add a slash before `content/` -- double check, as I usually having all rules in a single file -- much easier to manage).

Comment: Again many many thanks - brill do you have a website/blog with any more info/examples? as would love to learn how to change say page.php?foo=bar into bar.php/html

Comment: I have no blog or site. Post it as separate question and I'm sure that me or someone else will answer it.